# "using SQLite;" is grayed out

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I'm doing a multiplatform xamarin forms project. I am using SQLite for the database. I have the "sqlite-net pcl" nuget installed. I created a Model class within the main app

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using SQLite;

namespace MyApp.Models
{
    [Table("vegetables")]
    public class Vegetable
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int VegetableId { get; set; }
        [MaxLength (250), Unique]
        public string VegetableName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Using SQLite; is grayed out and Visual Studio is saying that it is unnecessary to include it. Typically when you type [Table("vegetables")] "Table" turns Blue and it indicates that it is a TableAttribute. In my code Table, PrimaryKey, etc. remain black and don't seem to have any association.

I'm following along with a sample project that I did from a textbook and it worked in the sample, and I'm following the same steps for my code but am running into this issue. What am I missing?

Comment: `TableAttribute` isn't part of `SQLite`. It's part of  `System.Data.Linq.Mapping` hence `using SQLite;` is still greyed out in visual studio. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Are there any updates for this issue?

Comment: which version are you using ?